# New factorial function without 0

Tags: python, factorial

So, the standard factorial function in python is defined as:

```
def factorial(x):
  if x == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return x * factorial(x-1)
```

Since n! := n * (n-1) * ... * 1, we can write n! as (n+1)! / (n+1). Thus 0! = 1 and we wouldn't need that if x == 0. I tried to write that in python to but I didn't work. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is  a recursive function (`return x * factorial(x-1)`) you must have an end condition (`if x == 0:`).

It is true that `n! == (n+1)! / (n+1)` and you could change your recursive call to :

```
def factorial(x):
    return factorial(x+1) / (x+1)
```

But that again would have no end condition -> endless recursion (you will calling the next (n+1)! and than the (n+2)! and so on forever (or until you'll get an exception)).

BTW, you can have the condition stop your execution at 1:

```
if x == 1:
    return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to use recursive function for things that are not limited, hence I suggest doing a little bit importing from the standard library

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def fact(x):
    if not isinstance(x, int) or x <= 0:
        raise Exception("math error")
    else:
        return reduce(operator.mul, range(1, x + 1), 1)

print(fact("string"))    
print(fact(-5))
print(fact(0))
print(fact(5))
```

Just realized that there is no need for a hustle like that:

```
def fact2(x):
    if not isinstance(x, int) or x <= 0:
        Exception("math error")
    else:
        y = 1
        while x > 1:
            y *= x
            x -= 1
        return y
```